# Unwanted warning in type argument why?

Tags: java

When I try to run the following program I am getting following warning which puts me in dilemma.

> Unused type arguments for the non generic method m() of type
>   TEST class; it should not be parameterized with arguments

```
void m2() {
    this.<String>m(); // warning here
}

int m() {
  return 1;
}
```

Now my question is if this not legal then why there is no compilation error ?

Comment: Well the generic type parameter `<String>` is not being used, hence cannot break anything.

Comment: If used will compiler flags an error ? I need to check

Comment: Are you are asking me a question, or making a statement?

Comment: I have updated my question , now method is returning int but still no error. If you could please update in answer the proper example so that I can understand it

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

```
MethodInvocation:
MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
ArgumentList:
Expression {, Expression}
```

According to java specification your code is valid, it syntatically matches the *ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )*.

Warning is probably generated by eclipse as a marker for potential place, which can behave strangely. I think it could be connected with matching potential method to a reference, however I can't give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

The code is syntactically correct. The warning is shown because, you're not using any type parameter for the method `m()` but trying to access it like one in line `this.<String>m();` You can define the method with a type parameter to fix the warning. I've added a sample piece of code, which will compile & run without warnings.

```
public class Test {
    void m2() {
        System.out.println(this.<String>m()); // Just printing the return value
    }

    <T> int m() {
      return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2().m2();
    }
}
```

***Note: I used a type parameter `T` for the method, `m()`. You cannot use any existing class as type parameter(String, Integer, etc.. & Classes defined by you). Since, this will cause another warning like, `The type parameter <TypeParameter> is hiding the type <TypeParameter>`***